# Why is arima in R one time step off?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I've recently noticed an odd behavior in a few timeseries methods. Let's fit an arima model (ar1) to the annual subspots data

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)

mod_arima <- arima(sunspot.year, c(1, 0, 0), xreg = 1700:1988)
```

Now, if we use `forecast` to get the fit on the model, it's a year off. Compare these two plots:

```
ggplot(sun_dat,
       aes(x = years, y = sunspots)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(y = fitted(mod_arima), 
            alpha = 0.5, lwd = 2, color = "blue")
```

[image]

To one where we delete the first value and tack on an NA at the end

```
ggplot(sun_dat,
       aes(x = years, y = sunspots)) +
  geom_line() +
   geom_line(y = c(fitted(mod_arima)[-1], NA), 
             alpha = 0.5, lwd = 2, color = "blue")
```

[image]

The second lines up perfectly, while the first is obviously one year off. What's going on here?

Comment: This is completely normal if the best prediction of $y_{t+1}$ is roughly $y_{t}$, which happens when the time series is a martingale difference sequence (typical e.g. for prices of shares and other financial instruments).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Richard Hardy writes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404650/why-is-arima-in-r-one-time-step-off#comment756501_404650): if your prediction $\hat{y}_{t+1}$ of $y_{t+1}$ is pretty much your last observation $y_t$, then of course you would expect $\hat{y}_{t+1}$ to line up with $y_t$, which would show exactly as the one year lag you wonder about.

And if you specify

```
arima(sunspot.year, c(1, 0, 0), xreg = 1700:1988)
```

then you fitted exactly that: an AR(1) model. The AR(1) coefficient is estimated to be about 0.81. (With an intercept. Also, if you add the year as a regressor, you will model a trend. Did you intend to do this?)

Incidentally, if you allow `auto.arima()` to fit a model, it will choose an ARIMA(2,1,3) model, which will not exhibit this lag:

[image: sunspots]

```
library(forecast)
model <- auto.arima(sunspot.year)
plot(sunspot.year)
lines(model$fit,col="red")
```

You could also include the known sunspot period of length 11, though `auto.arima()` won't automatically fit a SARIMA.

Answer (score 5):

You're fitting an $ARIMA(1,0,0)$ model to your data, which means that your fitted model has the form:

$\hat{Y}_{t+1}-m = a(Y_t-m) + \epsilon$

So it looks like it's a year off, because all the model is doing is copying the value from the current year $Y_t$, with an adjustment $a$ and a drift term, and making that the prediction for the next year $\hat{Y}_{t+1}$.

Your data looks highly cyclical, you might want to try fitting a seasonal ARIMA model instead of a simple AR(1) or AR(2).